# Sending a byte array in json using jackson

Tags: json, jackson

I want to form a JSON with two fields mimetype and value.The value field should take byte array as its value.

```
{

  "mimetype":"text/plain",

  "value":"dasdsaAssadsadasd212sadasd"//this value is of type byte[]

}
```

How can I accomplish this task?

As of now I am using `toString()` method to convert the byte array into String and form the JSON.

Answer (score 47):

If you are using Jackson for JSON parsing, it can automatically convert `byte[]` to/from Base64 encoded Strings via data-binding.

Or, if you want low-level access, both `JsonParser` and `JsonGenerator` have binary access methods (writeBinary, readBinary) to do the same at level of JSON token stream.

For automatic approach, consider POJO like:

```
public class Message {
  public String mimetype;
  public byte[] value;
}
```

and to create JSON, you could do:

```
Message msg = ...;
String jsonStr = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(msg);
```

or, more commonly would write it out with:

```
OutputStream out = ...;
new ObjectMapper().writeValue(out, msg);
```

Comment: is there any documentation on this and is this functionality still the same? i am sending a byte array from spring boot rest controller. so does that mean it will automatically get converted to a base 64 string via jackson?

Comment: That would depend on Spring Boot: if it uses Jackson for sending/receiving POJO with `byte[]` field, yes. Some other kind of data uses different converters (for example query parameters).

Comment: The thing to know with `readBinaryValue` is that it expects the binary to be base 64 encoded, (standard JSON). However in the wil it's possible to see non standard JSON document that may contain binary data.

Answer (score 20):

You can write your own CustomSerializer like this one:

```
public class ByteArraySerializer extends JsonSerializer<byte[]> {

@Override
public void serialize(byte[] bytes, JsonGenerator jgen,
        SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {
    jgen.writeStartArray();

    for (byte b : bytes) {
        jgen.writeNumber(unsignedToBytes(b));
    }

    jgen.writeEndArray();

}

private static int unsignedToBytes(byte b) {
    return b & 0xFF;
  }

}
```

This one returns an unsigned byte array representation instead of a Base64 string.

How to use it with your POJO:

```
public class YourPojo {

    @JsonProperty("mimetype")
    private String mimetype;
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private byte[] value;



    public String getMimetype() { return this.mimetype; }
    public void setMimetype(String mimetype) { this.mimetype = mimetype; }

    @JsonSerialize(using= com.example.yourapp.ByteArraySerializer.class)
    public byte[] getValue() { return this.value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }


}
```

And here is an example of it's output:

```json
{
    "mimetype": "text/plain",
    "value": [
        81,
        109,
        70,
        122,
        90,
        83,
        65,
        50,
        78,
        67,
        66,
        84,
        100,
        72,
        74,
        108,
        89,
        87,
        48,
        61
    ]
}
```

P.S.: This serializer is a mix of some answers that I found on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, this  worked for me. Also, I did some changes in ByteArraySerializer serialize() method. I need string representation of byte array.                                                                                     
String str = new String(bytes);
jgen.writeString(str);

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) which converts binary data to a string. Most programming languages have implementations of base64 encoding and decoding. If you want to decode/encode in a browser, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript).

Comment: But please be aware that there are various kinds of Base64.