# Kafka Serialize/Deserialize complex object

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka

I need the producer to serialize and send a custom object that contains a Bytebuffer (video chunk) and a String:

```
public class NvrWSBinaryMessage {
  private String messageUuid;
  private final ByteBuffer payload;
...
```

And have the consumer correctly deserialize.

I've not found a correct way to create a custom serializer/deserializer for the object having the ByteBuffer. I tried to send the object as a bytearray without any success.

Comment: I'm 99.% sure you have to store a `byte[]` on the message rather than a `ByteBuffer`. I assume you are using Avro, as this could be different if you are serialising in a different format.

Comment: Thanks Augusto, i'm not using Avro, should I?. Also if I change a bytbuffer for a bytearray, Should I serialize the whole object to byte array even if the object has a byte array?

Comment: You don't need to use Avro, no, but it'll let you send data without having to write a custom serializer

Answer (score 0):

There is a `ByteBufferSerializer` / `ByteBufferDeserializer` you could use for your kafka clients (producer/consumer), however, that would require you to send the `ByteBuffer payload` as the kafka message/record value and `String messageUuid` as the key. [serialization 2.8 docs](https://kafka.apache.org/28/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/package-summary.html)

If you don't have this flexibility, then I'd suggest leveraging jackson annotations (similiar to [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993617/how-to-deserialize-serialize-byte-array-using-jackson-and-wrapper-object/40994190)) on the object you want to send as the record value, and using the `JsonSerializer` / `JsonDeserializer` for your clients.

Serialization will convert an object into byte code format, so it gets tricky when passing an object holding bytes as a value to be serialized without any extra configuration. The annotations are used to remove any serialization ambiguity, allowing the Kafka provided serializers to do the job without issue.

Comment: Json doesn't have a bytes type, though, so are you suggesting base64 encoding? Why not use Avro or Protobuf?

Comment: Yes - a string of 0's and 1's shouldn't cause too much havoc to a project. If you're curious, check out that link. There isn't an issue with Avro/Protobuf, it could definitely be used to solve this problem. However, it brings a layer of complexity, one that might not be necessary to solve the problem.