# MimeType missing in Base64 encoded url

Tags: java, encoding, base64

I have requirement to pass an image in json request and I am using javax.Base64 encoder.

I am able to encode the image to Base64 but I found that mime type "**data:image/png;base64**" is missing in generate encoded String.

So, my encoded String looks like below :

> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPAAAABQCAAAAAACIqegAAABMEl**********

And, here is my simple code which I am trying with junit :

```
@Test
    public void getBiographicPanel() {
        byte[] image = bacodeGenerator.generateBarocdeImage("12345678");
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(image));
        System.out.println(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(image));

        assertNotNull(image);
    }
```

How, is that any way or input parameter present in Base64 API which can we configure to generate Base64 image content with MimeType like below ?

> **data:image/png;base64**,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS

Comment: I don't think it's the job of the encoder to add the MIME type

Comment: But if you will refer the questions and example on stackoverflow, most of the users has mentioned String with this header. So, I assuming that there must be some encoder which provides this meta data. In worst case, I need to append the meta data as prefix explicitly.

Comment: Could you link those questions? The MIME type is set prior to calling the remote endpoint.

Comment: I was referring this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546917/sending-a-byte-array-in-json-using-jackson . But I may be wrong. I may need append it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MIME` type is

> a two-part identifier for file formats and format contents transmitted
>   on the Internet.

That means if you don't need to exchange this file via internet protocols (e.g. HTTP), that type is absolutely irrelevant.

---

You're also confusing

```
data:image/png;base64
```

with a `MIME` type. That **is not** a media type.

`data:` is an actual URL format and is used to specify inline data inside the browser (see [IETF](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2397.txt)).
In your case it would mean "*hey browser! Look at this local resource encoded in Base64 to build-up the image!*".

This is tipically used in `<img />` tags, and must be set manually. That means you **have to know** the actual format of the data.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I got little confused due to some block on net. 
In my case, I am sending a json Map<String,Object> to remote service. And the value of map may be a String or a Base64 encoded image. 
So basically, I need a workaround to determine weather the the value is a String or Image on the remote service. 
Here, I think only way to add prefix like "image/png;base64" to Base64 encoded String which we can check on remote service to determine that the value is an image.

Comment: @GunjanShah the most correct way of carrying a MIME type is via HTTP headers (`Content-Type`). Will this map carry only the encoded/standard string, or other data also? If it has a mixture of data, than yes, you need to manually prefix the encoded string. You could also create a custom object format to hold the data and the format of the data `{ "data": "...", "format":  "image/png;base64" }`

Comment: yup, this map contains mixture of data. It may have String and byte[] type values. And I can not request format as request contract is fixed to call third party web services. So, I think, I can only ask them to check the prefix of the image.

Comment: @GunjanShah consider using a custom data format, like the one I specified above, for your `Map` values

Comment: I got another solution. We can use URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(bin) function. This method will return null if I pass input stream of normal String. And it return exact image type "PNG" if I pass input stream of an image. So I can use these of remote service to check if the contents are image or not.

Comment: @GunjanShah but you just said the request body content is mixed. So that won't work.

Comment: yup, Request body content  will be mixture of String and Object. But I tested URLConnection class. It returns null if input param is String or something other than image . And It returns exact image type if I pass Base64 encoded image. So it will work for me. By the way, your answer helped me to clear my misunderstanding about meta data prefix in Base64 encoded image. I am marking this response as Correct. Thank  you  !

Comment: @GunjanShah thanks for the update! Good to know for the future!